# How Ephemeral Diffie Hellman works?

Tags: openssl, encryption, diffie-hellman

can anybody please provide link which will clearly explains how ephemeral  Diffie hellman algorithm works (TLS_DHE_RSA_DES_256_CBC)?

Comment: I've voted to close as "off topic". You may wish to try http://crypto.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is described in TSL 1.0 and 1.1 RFCs, see RFC 2246 and RFC 4346.